# Почему не меняется значение переменной in?

Tags: java, for

Почему не меняется значение переменной in? Мне нужно выходить из внутреннего цикла после каждой его итерации. (поэтому стоит break)
Но почему значение переменной in не меняется?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: зачем тут вообще тогда внутренний цикл?

Comment: изучи тему постфиксного и префиксного инкремента

Comment: Мне нужно пройтись по матрице по диагонали(снизу вверх, с слева направо)
Поэтому использую циклы

Comment: "нужно выходить из внутреннего цикла после каждой его итерации"  === одна итерация === не нужен никакой цикл

Comment: по диагонали шагать по матрице - не нужен никакой break..... нужен if внутри второго цикла который смотрит если in === out - вот и главная диагональ

Comment: код должен быть текстом, а не картиной

Answer (score 1):

Значение переменной in не меняется, потому как переменная in видна только внутри вложенного цикла, а соответственно при каждом запуске вложенного цикла переменная in приравнивается = 0

Можете использовать подобное объявление:

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 10; i>0; i--){
  for(;j<10; j++){
    System.out.println(++j);
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

С переменной `in` происходит следующее:

```
in = 0  # начали внутренний цикл
  break # закончили внутренний цикл
in = 0  # начали внутренний цикл
  break # закончили внутренний цикл
in = 0  # начали внутренний цикл
  break # закончили внутренний цикл
```

Потому она и "не меняется".